# Python - Project Euler #80, understanding the error

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, precision, square

Project Euler problem #80 seems straightforward:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=80

Using the decimal module to calculate the square root to a given precision:

```
from decimal import Decimal, localcontext

def prob80():
    total = 0
    for x in range(1,100):
        with localcontext() as ctx:
            ctx.prec = 100
            total+=sum([int(i) for i in str(Decimal(x).sqrt())[2:]])
    return total
print prob80()
```

I return 40308 which I understand is someway off the correct answer. For the digital sums of the square root of the first ten natural numbers I return:

0
475
441
0
472
470
397
463
0
456

Where's the error here? I think it's down to some sort of rounding error but I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: if you are suspecting rounding error you should be treating rumbers with integer roots differently. Meaning disregarding them completely, not hoping their first 100 decimal digits add up to 0

Comment: If I disregard the numbers with integer roots I return the same result

Comment: i.e. squares = [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
      for x in range(1,100):
  if x not in squares:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blog.dreamshire.com/project-euler-80-solution/

> First, the 100 digits include digits to the right and left of the decimal.
>
> Second, make sure to calculate more digits than are necessary to avoid rounding errors as it affects some of the numbers.

```
from decimal import Decimal, localcontext

def prob80():
    total = 0
    for x in range(1,100):
        print x
        with localcontext() as ctx:
            ctx.prec = 105
            if len(str(Decimal(x).sqrt())) == 1:
                total+=0
            else:
                a = sum([int(i) for i in str(Decimal(x).sqrt())[2:101]])+int(str(Decimal(x).sqrt())[0])
                total+=a
    return total
print prob80()
```

Comment: Ummm don't you once say that one has to count in 1st digit, but then for squares of natural numbers you don't count it? Sum of all decimal digits of `4` (in base of `10`) is `2`, or have I miss understood something? I.e. there should be no `if`

Comment: "Sum of all decimal digits of **square root of** `4` (in base of `10`) is `2`" of course.

Comment: the problem says sum only for irrational numbers.

Comment: Oh, this wasn't posted in the question. I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You made two mistakes which cancelled each other out for the example case.

1. You did not count in 1st digit `1`
2. You set precision too low by one digit. Last digit almost always contain some rounding error. 100th and 101st digits of `sqrt(2)` are `27`, so when you used `prec=100` it got rounded up to `3`, making up for the 1st error.

Btw. there is a straightforward implementation. `Decimal` object has [`as_tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.as_tuple) method:

> Return a named tuple representation of the number: `DecimalTuple(sign, digits, exponent)`.

So you can go with:

```
decimal.getcontext().prec = 101
i = 2
sum(decimal.Decimal(i).sqrt().as_tuple()[1][:100]) # [1] is `digits`; [:100] are 1st 100
```

No need for string conversions nor "iffing".